# rails delegate all attributes to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates

I am wondering if it is possible to delegate all columns of a model to another model in one line. For now What I have been doing is delegate one attribute at a time like this 
`:delegate :a,:b,:c => :modelA`. So is it possible to delegate all three attributes to another model? I have a model with about 20 columns which I would like to delegate to another model. 
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to delegate all attributes to another model? This seems like a code smell.

Comment: Model.colum_names provides you with an array containing all columns.

Comment: @apneadiving but I used to delegate :name,:name=,:name? to the parent model.This won't solve that issue..whattudu?